# How to solve this MySQL COUNT query?

Tags: mysql, database, count

Three table are given:

```
customer(cust_id, name, address, sales_id)
orders(order_id, cust_id,date, sales_id)
salesman(sales_id,commision)
```

and you have to write an MySQL query to **"count the salesman by their order_id and date"**. Is  the question is correct? if yes, how can I solve this.

Comment: this sounds like you're just asking for an answer to a homework question

Comment: What does counting a human by order_id and date mean? Is that supposed to mean "Count the distinct number of salesman by order_id and date?"... which also doesn't make sense. Or "Count the distinct order_ids for each salesman for each distinct date?". Furthermore, what is the relationship for these tables. they all seem to be referencing eachother's ids multiple times. Are you writing this homework question or trying to solve it? If the latter, I would ask the teacher for clarification.

Comment: No, It was a question of recruitments examination. @distrill

Comment: question is ot clear, do you need total orders per salesman and per date ? or number of sales man per date and order

Comment: @EngrMd.AshrafulHaque see the solution below

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but the codes below will give you an idea of how to get aggregated results and you can play around / adjust based on your needs

```
select 
date,
sales_id,
count(order_id) as total_orders_per_date_and_sales_id

from orders
group by 1,2
```

if you need the total salesman per date then you can do this:

```
select 
date,
count(sales_id) as total_sales_man_per_date

from orders
group by 1
```

if one order has multiple sales owners, then you can find total salesman per order id

```
select 
orders_id,
count(salesman) as total_sales_man_involved_per_order
from orders
group by 1
```

if you need total commission per salesman per date:

```
select 
orders.date,
orders.sales_id,
sum(salesman.comission) as total_comssion_per_salesman_per_date
from orders
left join salesman 
on orders.sales_id = salesman.sales_id 
group by 1,2
```

total number of distinct salesman

```
select 
count(distinct sales_id) as total_unique_salesman
from salesman
```